# Canvas, iframe and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: http, iframe, canvas, processing.js, cross-domain-policy

I am getting crazy with this problem, and hope there is a solution or workaround.
I have a canvas inside an iframe, in a different domain (for security reasons). This canvas shows a Processing.js animation/drawing. I need to allow the canvas to load image files that are located on the same domain.

`index.html` with the `iframe` is in **domain.com**

`index.html` with the `canvas` is in **sub.domain.com**

Now I know for sure that:

1. The canvas can load/visualize a remote image but cannot access a remote image data (pixels).
2. The canvas can fully access an image file on the same domain, unless it is played in an iframe (!?).
3. Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin header simply allows to access files on other domains.
4. The canvas does not support/consider Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers at all.

Is there a way to bypass all these security limits and simply get a canvas played in an iframe to load an image file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem (and saw that nobody answered). Actually I forgot something... I was using the `sandbox` attribute in the `iframe` tag and that was the problem. Once removed, images started to be accessible within the canvas, in Firefox and Chrome at least (did not test IE yet). Anyway, the `sandbox` attribute still has a very bad support and is probably totally useless in a cross-domain scenario.

So. I can confirm that with a normal `iframe` (without any `sandbox` parameter) there are no problems when loading images into a `canvas`, within an iframe, *if and only if* the image is in the same domain of the `canvas` page.

Comment: I have the same problem but I have to preserve the `sandbox` attribute.

Is there a way to force Canvas to work in `sub.domain.com` context? It looks like Canvas in iframe/sandbox thinks that it is in top-document `www.domain.com` context.

Did anybody solve it? It is 2019 and the behavior is consistent in both FF and Chrome so I suppose it is intentional and not a bug.